# Nullpointerexception in webview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm having problems with a webview inside a fragment. I'm getting a error message saying *"java.lang.nullpointerexception"* at this line: *myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());*. I have googled and googled but not found a solution. Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

**FragmentB.java**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 *
 */
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

public FragmentB() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private View mContentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView)mContentView. findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.nellienova.com");
    return mContentView;
    }




}
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the right xml file. I have done this before by mistakenly loading another layout file. You have webview.xml typed above that file but you inflating R.layout.fragment_b

Edit

Each fragment has its own layout file. You can reuse layouts and add multiple layouts to one xml file but through code your fragment will only inflate the file you refer to.

If you want to include other files you have to use include statements to pull those other files in to your xml before you can interact with objects in the other xml files. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more details about include statements. Example below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:layout_height=”match_parent”
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

<TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for some good information about fragments. Spend a little time with it and it will save you lots of time troubleshooting problems.

Comment: That's correct. fragment_b.xml is a fragment layout with a temporary textview saying "Fragment B". webview.xml is a webview layout (as shown above). The latter has the id "webview", and is used for the webview. I'm not sure if I'm doing this the correct way. I have a swipe tab layout with four fragments (A-D) and inside of Fragment B, I want to display the content of a website.

Comment: So you are saying that your WebView is inside the R.layout.fragment_b file? If not, move it there and see if you still get the error.

Comment: No, I had them in two seperate files. As soon as I placed the webview inside the fragment_b file, it worked like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! I am going to update my answer to make it more information to others.